# JS function to detect primes not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, primes, factorial

I'm trying to make a function to determine if a number is prime on JS. The method I'm using for this is the Wilson's theorem, which states that, in short, if `(num - 1)! % num` is equal to `num -1`, then `num` is prime. To implement this function I made another function to calculate the factorial of a given number. I also added a conditional operator to return `false` if the given number is smaller or equal than 1, to fulfill a condition of prime numbers.

The factorial function works just fine (I checked its return values), but for some reason, the Wilson's theorem function has issues. I worked trough a lot of primes and determined that below 23 the function will work, and above 29 (the first prime after 23) the function won't (including 29).

Now, I know that there are much simpler ways to implement a function that serves this purpose, yet I want to try to use the Wilson's theroem and really don't understand why this function doesn't work. Below you can se my code and the tests I made for the function. Please leave a comment if you notice any problems that my code might have or if you know any way I could improve my functions to reach higher optimization or to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
// Factorial function
let factorial = function(num) {
  let outp = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      outp *= i;
  }
  return outp;
}

// Prime tester function
let isPrime = x => x <= 1 ? false : factorial(x-1) % x == x-1;

// Test function
console.log(isPrime(7));  // Should return: true, returns: true
console.log(isPrime(23));  // Should return: true, returns: true
console.log(isPrime(29));  // Should return: true, returns: false
console.log(isPrime(101));  // Should return: true, returns: false
```

If it is relevant, I am using node.js, but I also tested it on online compilers and observed no difference.

Comment: The main problem is that computing a factorial is quite expensive, and you can't compute it accurately beyond a relatively low threshold due to number representation limitations. A simple classic "Seive" implementation will be *much* more efficient.

Comment: @Pointy I guess that makes sense. It still bothers me, though, that the function will fail by returning `false` instead of `undefined` or raising an internal error. Thanks anyways for your answer, I'll make sure to check that implementation method.

Comment: A javascript number only keeps about 17 decimal places (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) but 29! is about 30 digits long.  You are asking for equality without enough precision...

Comment: @JayBuckman Yes, apparently that's exactly the problem. Thank you for your answer and your reference, I'll make sure to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern versions of Javascript support arbitrary precision integers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), which can be used to compute large integers exactly:

```js
// Factorial function
let factorial = function (num) {
    let outp = 1n; // the `n` suffix indicates a `BigInt` constant
    for (let i = 1n; i <= num; i++) {
        outp *= i;
    }
    return outp;
}

// Prime tester function
let isPrime = x => x <= 1n ? false : factorial(x - 1n) % x == x - 1n;

// Test function
console.log(isPrime(7n));  
console.log(isPrime(23n)); 
console.log(isPrime(29n)); 
console.log(isPrime(101n));
```

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks for your answer. It actually fixes my code. Apparently I can calculate much bigger primes with that data type, yet I realized that this method is not that efficient anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work for 29 and bigger numbers is JavaScript precision limit. 29! is too big number to store so it is kinda rounded. (It can even be infinity for larger numbers). You can store your number as string or array. But then you'll have to implement multiplication yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about that, but it makes a lot of sense. Maybe it will work if I store it in a string, I'll try that.